# Docker compose stops multiple services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I hope I didn't miss anything simple from the manual.
The structure is:

```
/home/user
   /foo1/bar1/docker/
                   Dockerfile
                   docker-compose.yml
   /foo2/bar2/docker/
                   Dockerfile
                   docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  foo1-bar1:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DOCKER_SERVER_ROOT_DIR: ${DOCKER_SERVER_ROOT_DIR}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: foo1-bar1:v1
    container_name: foo1-bar1-v1
```

The same is for `foo-bar-v2`.
Both of them I successfully run as:

```
cd /foo1/bar1/docker/
docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
⠿ Container foo1-bar1-v1  Started 

cd /foo2/bar2/docker/
docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
⠿ Container foo2-bar2-v1  Started
```

The question is, why does it stop both of them when I try to stop only 1? Service names, container names, image names are different...

```
user@vm:~/foo1/bar1/docker$ docker-compose stop
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container foo1-bar1-v1    Stopped                                                                                                                                                                                         
 ⠿ Container foo2-bar2-v2    Stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose has the concept of `projects`. Run `docker-compose --help` and you will see:

```
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the, first specified, Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name
```

So in your case, both your services belong to the same project named `docker`.

You can actually run `docker-compose -p docker ps` and you will see both your services.

You can also override this by specifying your own project name independent of the directory name.

My version of docker-compose (Docker Compose version v2.10.2 MacOS) does warn me that there are orphan containers in this project when I replicate your setup. Also it doesn't automatically stop "orphan" services and gives a warning that the network could not be removed either.

This is also another interesting fact: both services run on the same network (docker_default) only because the project name (folder name) is the same.

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Thank you, I got it! `docker-compose -p docker ps` really shows multiple containers in the same group. Plus I've also noticed that I have the same warning: `WARN[0000] Found orphan containers ([foo1-bar1-v1 foo2-bar2-v1]) for this project.`

Comment: for me i did not seeing anything with docker-compose -p docker ps.
but just adding a random -p and some name, allowed the second container to start...although it created a different network for it.  wondering if it's possible in a single docker-compose, to reference another service defined in a different director, with different environment files.  like how to dyou specify different environment files for the services are on a command line?

Comment: @mike01010 you can load more than one docker-compose.yml file using multiple `-f` arguments. With that you might be able to reference other services. However I wouldn't do it since it will make it very difficult in the future to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [specify the service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_stop/) to stop. Otherwise it will stop all services.

`docker compose stop [OPTIONS] [SERVICE...]`

here : `docker-compose stop foo1-bar1`

Comment: Does not it automatically check the services from the docker-compose file that is in the folder? There are also another services that are running in the same way (from the other images) It does not stop them. These two foo1/foo2 use the same Dockerfile (content). Maybe that is the reason.